# gitlab pipeline fails during build

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, continuous-integration, gitlab

I'm new to using gitlab CI. I am deploying a gulp website through gitlab and everything works fine locally, and deployes without errors, up until my latest commit. I get the following error during pipeline build on gitlab.

```
npm info lifecycle undefined~preshrinkwrap: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~shrinkwrap: undefined
npm info lifecycle undefined~postshrinkwrap: undefined
npm info ok 
up to date in 7.152s
$ ./scripts/build_website.sh
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I will appreciate any help on this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried installing gulp-sass with `npm install gulp-sass` ?

Comment: What runner type are you using, and what exactly does the shell script do. It looks like you have dependencies installed locally that are not in your package.json or your script doesn't do an `npm install`